# Adding controls to form using timers

Tags: c#, timer, controls

So I am trying to add controls to a form, And I am using a kind of a work around so I could add a control through a static function, I did it like this:

```
Control c = this;
Button b = new Button();
//....
c.Controls.Add(b);
```

This works, so I have been using this method to add controls. But now I am using timers and it doesnt work

```
Control c = this;
Timer t = new Timer(500);
t.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(t_Elapsed);


public static void t_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
Button b = new Button();
//...
c.Controls.Add(b);
}
```

The function `t_Elapsed` is run, and the code there is being executed, but the line `c.Controls.Add(b)` doesn't work.

Comment: What does *doesn't work* mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with your code:

1. Why use a static event handler and then use a work-around to access an instance variable when you could just use a non-static event handler in the first place?
2. The timer class you use is `System.Timers.Timer`, there are several more different timer classes, having slightly different behavior. A comparison can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx).

When you modify the UI in any way you have to do that from the UI thread. The `System.Timers.Timer` *can* invoke the event handler on the UI thread, but only if you provide a synchronization object, which is any object implementing the `ISynchronizeInvoke` interface, e.g. `Form`.

You can set the synchronization object using `t.SynchronizingObject = this`, if `this` references an instance of the `Form` class.

Answer (score 0):

You must access controls on the thread that they were created in.

Your timer elapsed event fires on a different thread to the UI, so you need to marshal the call onto the UI thread.

This can be done with `Invoke`:

```
    void t_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
        {
            Button b = new Button();
            c.Controls.Add(b);
        });
    }
```